# How to generate a duplicate video streaming URL & expire it after an hour

Tags: url, amazon-ec2, rails-3.1

Scenario: A customer comes to my site & purchases a video. I generate a duplicate streaming URL which works for an hour, so that he can download the video and then the URL link expires automatically.

Application Framework: Rails 3.1
Hosting environment EC2.

Answer (score 2):

Options:

1. Create the video as a file on the server side in a special directory and link directly to the file. Delete this temporary file after an hour. This is probably not a very good option, for instance because you will need duplicate copies of a file.
2. When a user asks for a video, create a random number (or hash) and store that number in a database, together with the file asked for and the current time. When a user visits a download link (something like *http://page.com/download/some8374random1278hash*), check if the hash he asks for exists in the database and if the time it was created is not more than an hour ago. If this is true, then return the file contents of the asked-for file back to the customer's browser.

Comment: Link to a file doesn't cost you disk space other than a block for metadata, so linking is IMHO a very good option. OTOH serving video with Rails is going to be expensive compared to server doing it "natively".

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 supports the creation of authenticated URLs with expiration times.  You can leave the videos on S3 (non-public) and then generate the authenticated, expiring URLs at purchase time.

A benefit of this is that your web server doesn't have to handle all the downloading of the file.  Amazon S3 takes care of this at the same network transfer rate as you would have been paying for serving it from your EC2 instance.

Data transfer between your EC2 instance and S3 is free.

Answer (score 0):

How about integrating the Dropbox API? Share the folder ( which contains purchased files ) and revoke the share permission after some time.